# How to fix org.springframework.jdbc.BadSqlGrammarException: PreparedStatementCallback; bad SQL grammar

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot

I am using a SQL query to delete records older than 15 days. I have a column in table which stores the date after which it has to be deleted.

I tried using :

```
DELETE FROM emarket 
WHERE postdate < < DATEADD(mi,-15,GETDATE())';";
```

where postdate is the column in which the date to be deleted is stored.

This is the error I get :

> Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Unterminated string
>   literal started at position 63 in SQL DELETE FROM emarket WHERE
>   postdate << DATEADD(mi,-15,GETDATE())';. Expected  char

Comment: Where in [the Postgres manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions.html) did you find `dateadd()` or `getdate()`?

Comment: The error you have shown indicates that you are defining the SQL statement inside your Java code incorrectly. Please **[edit]** your question and add the Java code that _uses_ that statement (and fix the invalid use of `getdate()` - because that will be your next problem)